# how to define a function in which we receive a string as a parameter and return the sum of the digits multiplied by two?

Tags: python, python-3.x

A solution using a loop is expected.

As an example, the following code fragment:

```
total  = double_add_digits_in_string("xx1xx2xx3xx")
print (total)
```

Output:

```
12
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to explain better, but this can help:

```
s = "xx1xx2xx3xx"

result = 0
for char in s:
    try: 
        result += int(char) #try to parse int 
    except:
        pass

print(2 * result)
```

Output:

```
12
```

Anorher way:

```
for char in s:
    if char.isdigit():
        result += int(char)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def double_add_digits_in_string(s):
    summ = 0
    for char in s:
        if char.isdigit():
            summ += int(char)
    return 2 * summ

print double_add_digits_in_string('xx1xx2xx3xx')
> 12
```